# Animated map using geom_sf and ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Yo will find a copy of this question on [GitHub](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1923).

I try to animate a map using ggplot with geom_sf and ggplotly. In the following example the map does not change over time. For example, animating a scatterplot is possible. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
world$year <- 2010

world2 <- world
world2$year <- 2011
world2$pop_est <- 1000000

world3 <- bind_rows(world, world2)
   
plt <- ggplot(world3, aes(fill = pop_est, frame = year)) +
  geom_sf()

ggplotly(plt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
library(gganimate)
world3 %>% ggplot() +
  geom_sf() + aes(fill = pop_est) +
  transition_states(year)
```